# modify specific columns based on another column by using awk and gsub

Tags: bash, xubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, linux-headers

I have a file (file1) with millions of rows and columns. An example of data are:

```
"col1","col2","col3","col4","col5","col6"
"AAA",0,5,10,"BGB",50
"BBB",4,7,10,"BFD",76
"AAA",15,0,0,"BGB",20
"AAA",10,13,10,"DDD",23
```

I want to find all lines that have AAA in col1 and then get all the rows that have BGB in col5. And finally, decrease 50% of every value in col2, col3, col4, and col6 (Ignore if cell values are 0 or blank). And print all the lines of the file.  So, my output will look like following:

```
"col1","col2","col3","col4","col5","col6"
"AAA",0,2.5,5,"BGB",25
"BBB",4,7,10,"BFD",76
"AAA",7.5,0,0,"BGB",10
"AAA",10,13,10,"DDD",23
```

I have been trying the following, but could not make it work (also, could not figure out how to use multiple columns in gsub)

```
grep AAA file1 | awk -F "," '$5~/BGB/ {gsub($6,\substr($6,1,length($6)-1)*0.50\, $6}1'
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Ubuntu?

Comment: Or Windows Subsystem for Linux (as tagged)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

awk can match patterns like grep does, so you almost never need grep and awk in a pipeline.

You could do

```bsh
 awk  '
    BEGIN {FS = OFS = ","}
    $1 ~ /AAA/ && $5 ~ /BGB/ {
        if ($2) $2 = $2 / 2
        if ($3) $3 = $3 / 2
        if ($4) $4 = $4 / 2
        if ($6) $6 = $6 / 2
    }
    1
' file
```

Or, if you want to make the columns to reduce more dynamic

```bsh
awk -v "columns=2,3,4,6" '
    BEGIN {
        FS = OFS = ","
        n = split(columns, a, /,/)
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++) cols[a[i]]=1
    }
    $1 ~ /AAA/ && $5 ~ /BGB/ {
        for (c in cols) if ($c) $c = $c / 2
    }
    1
' file
```